# python multiprocessing pool malloc error

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, pool

I am new to python parallel programming.
I am trying to extract SIFT features from lots of images (~100,000) using OpenCV in python. It seems like a very easy parallelization which is very similar to the parfor in matlab. I checked for the python parallel module and found out that multiprocessing module might be suitable for this case. Thus, I tried to use Pool class in multiprocessing module. As an initial test, I first test on total 900 images. My code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import multiprocessing as mp


def extract_SIFT(img_name):
    img = cv2.imread(img_name)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #detect the SIFT keypoints and the descriptors.
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
    kp, des=sift.detectAndCompute(gray,None)

    return des

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    img_path = './images/'
    img_names = glob.glob(img_path + '*.jpg')
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    sift_features = pool.map(extract_SIFT, img_names)
```

However, after try to run the script, I kept get the following errors:

> Python(1692) malloc: *** error for object 0x100f11000: pointer being freed was not allocated
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> Python(1693) malloc: *** error for object 0x100ed7e08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> Python(1690) malloc: *** error for object 0x100ff6000: pointer being freed was not allocated
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>
> Python(1699) malloc: *** error for object 0x100cf4800: double free
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I only list part of those errors, however it all seems relate to Python malloc. Can anyone please give me some hint on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You're processing 100,000 images by using `pool.map` you'd be getting a list of all your results in memory. You might want to alter that behaviour.

Comment: I see, you are correct. However, I tried with fewer images but still get the same errors. I will update the my question to make it more clear.

Comment: From error messages, some data may be shared among processes. Some process freed (deallocate) data(memory area) and then other process freed same data, "pointer being freed was not allocated" error may occur.

Comment: There is no data being shared here, unless he's doing something else that he hasn't shown in the code.

Comment: The code I posted is exactly the same as I used. Are there any possibilities that some underlying data sharing exist in cv2 module? However, I think that for multiprocessing module, all process should have their own memory for specific variables. Please clarify me if I am wrong.